# Sum of Primes of the form 6j+1 and 6j-1

Tags: number-theory

Can anyone tell me if the following relationship regarding the sum of primes of the form $6j+1$ and the sum of primes of the form $6j-1$ for large n has been proved. Namely

$$
\sum_{\substack{p \le n,\\ p\equiv 1\bmod{6}}}{p}\,\,\approx\,\,\sum_{\substack{p \le n,\\ p\equiv -1\bmod{6}}}{p}
$$

Comment: Yes.  This can be seen easily from PNT-AP (Prime Number Theorem for Arithmetic Progressions) combined with a routine partial summation argument.  Both sides should be asymptotic to $\frac14 n^2 / \log n$.